# Missing function's return type declaration - do declarations increate efficiency

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Is there any benefit in including a return type declaration in a php class function? Is this better:

```
public function team_classes(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(TeamClass::class, 'activity_id', 'id');
}
```

is the above better than the following?

```
public function team_classes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TeamClass::class, 'activity_id', 'id');
}
```

and if so, is it only for the programmers eye's or does it increase efficiency / speed?

Comment: This makes PHP provide type checking for you so you don't have to do it yourself. This allows you to write code faster because IDEs can provide better code completion. It also makes your code less error prone because PHP handles the type checking and therefore you can avoid issues from typos and things like that. It does not make the code faster or more efficient in fact it might even make it slower than not having any type checking. However in practical scenarios you will have to use type-checking in some form or another

Comment: Which kind of benefit are you thinking of? Performance? Memory? Safety on upgrading the code?

Comment: I think you're looking at it from the wrong side. High performance languages like C or Rust require strong typing because loose typing implementation adds overhead. PHP has been loosely typed from the beginning, but it didn't get type hints or return types for _performance_; it did to ease writing complex applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, older versions of PHP did not have this feature so they called PHP as duck taped but after the latest version you have return types and typed variables etc. If return type is important or argument types of your function it is a good practice to put return types.

In your code, you better put these return types or variable types because you do not want to assign some string to an integer or something like that, or sending collection while the function expecting you to send array. It will protect you as a developer from doing mistakes or doing less mistakes and it honestly it will make your life easier when debuging your code.

You can also use like this:

```
use lluminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

public function team_classes(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(TeamClass::class, 'activity_id', 'id');
}
```

It is good practice to use FQDN

Answer (score 5):

Adding return type declaration is *recommended*, but *not mandatory*. It provides you with advanced IDE autocompletion and type compatibility support.

For instance, if you don't have type declaration on your relationship, your IDE will most likely not provide you with relationship methods.

Another reason why you might want to opt in using types is runtime type checking. Try adding an incorrect return type to your example above (instead of returning HasMany type use anything else). This will throw an exception whenever you use that method.

As for speed: it almost does not impact your application. You can find type-hinting comparisons online, but from what I see the difference is about 2-5ms.

Overall, this provides better IDE support and implicit type declarations, which make developer life easier.

Answer (score -1):

// PHP function created
// Variant 1
`function test($x, $y) { // return parametr` return $x + $y;`

}
echo test(5, 8);`

// Variant 2 error
`function testStart() { echo "Result Error"; } testStart();`

// Variant 3 successful
`function testStar(): void { echo "Result Successful"; } testStar();`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How is all this code related to the question after all?

Comment: Please format your code as code. Please add explanation to the answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34250509)